# How can I access Gtk# widgets in code in MonoDevelop?

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

First, I am new to Monodevelop and Gtk# (but have experience with Visual Studio, C# and Winforms).

In Monodevelop I designed a form by dragging widgets onto it. I entered a value for the Name and (the same or a different value) for the MemberName. However I can't access the widgets in code.

In Visual Studio there is a form.Designer.cs which contains the code that creates the controls. What is the equivalent in MonoDevelop? I would like to examine the code so I can learn from it, and to find out how I can access a widget in code.

I am using MonoDevelop 5.5, Mono 3.10.0 on Linux Mint 17.1 64-bit.

(This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284594/cant-access-my-widgets-in-the-code-editor), but that answer doesn't help me).

Comment: Also, if code is compiled, code-completion should help you access widgits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GTK# generated code will be in a .cs file inside a **gtk-gui** directory inside your project. The .cs file will have a similar name to your widget class name but will have the full namespace of the class as part of its name.

```
MyWidget.cs
gtk-gui/MyGtkApp.MyWidget.cs
```

Also you will need to compile your project before the code is generated. The new member names should be available from within the widget's class.

Comment: The missing part for me was the need to compile the project first. It wasn't in a compilable state, but now it is and I can see the designer code.